# How to join 3 tables in SQL without duplicates?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, inner-join, aggregate-functions

I have this work:

> We have to get players with at least 30,000 points in their career, who have won a prize and are still alive.

And I have in my sql 3 different tables for this information.

I can obtain the players with more than 30K and still alive with this code:

```
SELECT players.playerID, lastName, SUM(points) AS AllPoints, deathDate, 
FROM players
INNER JOIN players_teams  ON players.playerID = players_teams.playerID  
GROUP BY players.playerID, lastName, deathDate  
HAVING SUM(points) > 30000 AND deathDate = "0000-00-00"
```

and I have:

```
playerID    lastName    AllPoints   deathDate
0   abdulka01   Abdul-Jabbar    38387.0 0000-00-00
1   ervinju01   Erving  30026.0 0000-00-00
2   jordami01   Jordan  32292.0 0000-00-00
3   malonka01   Malone  36928.0 0000-00-00
```

So only 4 players have these two characteristics.

But if I want the 3 tables that tell me what player have a award, it give me the wrong result.

This is my try:

```
SELECT players.playerID, lastName, sum(points), award, deathDate
FROM players
INNER JOIN players_teams ON players.playerID = players_teams.playerID  
INNER JOIN awards_players ON players.playerID = awards_players.playerID  
GROUP BY players.playerID, lastName, award, deathDate
HAVING award IS NOT NULL and deathDate = "0000-00-00"
```

But the query gives me:

```
playerID    lastName    sum(points) award   deathDate
0   abdulka01   Abdul-Jabbar    191935.0    All-Defensive First Team    0000-00-00
1   abdulka01   Abdul-Jabbar    230322.0    All-Defensive Second Team   0000-00-00
2   abdulka01   Abdul-Jabbar    383870.0    All-NBA First Team  0000-00-00
3   abdulka01   Abdul-Jabbar    191935.0    All-NBA Second Team 0000-00-00
4   abdulka01   Abdul-Jabbar    76774.0 Finals MVP  0000-00-00
... ... ... ... ... ...
786 wisewi01    Wise    19454.0 All-ABA Second Team 0000-00-00
787 wisewi01    Wise    19454.0 All-Defensive Team  0000-00-00
788 worthja01   Worthy  32640.0 All-NBA Third Team  0000-00-00
789 worthja01   Worthy  16320.0 Finals MVP  0000-00-00
790 youngth01   Young   4534.0  All-Rookie Second Team  0000-00-00
```

And as you can see, the table gives the same player repeat and the query makes a add each point for each award. For example If X have 3 awards in 1997, the query multiplies by 3 their points.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Two SQL LEFT JOINS produce incorrect result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464037/two-sql-left-joins-produce-incorrect-result)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that a player may have multiple awards - in that case, the second join "multiplies" the rows, and the total points go off.

Since you just want to check if the player has *any* award, I would recommend `exists`:

```
select p.playerid, p.lastname, sum(pt.points) as allpoints, p.deathdate
from players p
inner join players_teams pt on pt.playerid = p.playerid
where 
    p.deathdate = "0000-00-00"
    and exists (select 1 from awards_players ap where ap.playerID = p.playerID)
group by p.playerid, p.lastname, p.deathdate  
having sum(pt.points) > 30000
```

Note that I prefixed all columns in the query  with the table they belong to, which makes it easier to red. Also note that the condition on `deathdate` belongs to the `where` clause rather than to the `having` clause, which operates on aggregate expressions (although MySQL allows it).

We could go one sqtep further with subquerires, and use a lateral join to retrieve the total points, so there is no aggregation at all in the outer query (this requires MySQL 8.0.14 at least):

```
select p.playerid, p.lastname, pt.allpoints, p.deathdate
from players p
cross join lateral (
    select sum(pt.points) as allpoints 
    from players_teams pt 
    where pt.playerid = p.playerid
) p
where 
    p.deathdate = "0000-00-00"
    and exists (select 1 from awards_players ap where ap.playerID = p.playerID)
    and pt.allpoints > 30000
```